# Solution to a trigonometric equation involving different coefficients

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve $x$ in the next equation:
$$A\sin(x+y)+\sin(2x)=0\,,$$
Where $A$ can take any real value.

I have tried to use the Prosthaphaeresis Formulas (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html), but I don't see a way to get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess you've got here:
$$
A\sin x\cos y + A\cos x\sin y + 2\sin x\cos x = 0 \tag{1}
$$
from here you can either go via $\sin x = z, \cos x = \sqrt{1 - z^2} $ or a bit more elegant [tangent half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula), namely $\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2},\cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ which turn $(1)$ in a polynomial equation in $t$ of the $4$-th degree. For that you have some analytical formulas for the roots. Not sure whether this is very useful though.